# Maximize sum of matrix after deleting K rows and K columns

Tags: algorithms, optimization, dynamic-programming, matrices

You're given a `m` by `n` matrix filled with positive integers, as well as some integer `k` (0 <= `k` <= `min(m, n)`). After deleting exactly `k` rows and `k` columns (deleting can be thought of as replacing a row/column with all zeros), what's the maximum sum of remaining cells in the matrix you can achieve?

I recently thought of this problem after misreading a somewhat similar problem, but I'm not sure what the most optimal solution is. I'm also interested in the specific case where k = 1.

Comment: Please clarify: is there an upper bound on cells? Is your maximum sum just the $\sum_{i\leq n, h\leq m}a_{i,h}$?